# How can I create a method that checks if a string starts with a capitalized letter?

Tags: ruby

So far I have:

```
def capitalized?(str)
  str[0] == str[0].upcase
end
```

THe problem wit this is that it returns `true` for strings like `"12345"`, `"£$%^&"` and`"9ball"` etc. I would like it to only return true if the first character is a capital letter.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `match?` to return true if the first character is a letter in the range of `A` to `Z` both uppercase or not:

```
def capitalized?(str)
  str.match?(/\A[A-Z]/)
end

p capitalized?("12345") # false
p capitalized?("fooo")  # false
p capitalized?("Fooo")  # true
```

Also you can pass a regular expression to `start_with?`:

```
p 'Foo'.start_with?(/[A-Z]/) # true
p 'foo'.start_with?(/[A-Z]/) # false
```

Comment: What about `capitalized?("FooF")` ??

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a nicer way to do it with regex, but keeping this ruby based, you can make an array of capital letters:

```
capital_letters = ("A".."Z")
```

Then you can check if your first letter is in that array:

```
def capitalized?(str)
  capital_letters = ("A".."Z")
  capital_letters.include?(str[0])
end
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
def capitalized?(str)
  ("A".."Z").include?(str[0])
end
```

Comment: You don't need to convert the range to an array. Range implements `include?`.

Comment: Sure, but you need to convert to an array or you just get 2 letters :)

Comment: `Range#cover?` is more efficient than `Range#include?` because the former only checks the endpoints of the range.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid character ranges if possible, because without knowing the encoding, you can never be sure what is in a range. In your case, it is unnecessary. A simple

```
/^[[:upper:]]/ =~ str
```

would do. See [here](https://relishapp.com/jarhart/rattler/docs/extended-matching-syntax/posix-character-classes) for the definition of POSIX character classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def capitalized?(str)
  str[0] != str[0].downcase
end

capitalized? "Hello"           #=> true
capitalized? "hello"           #=> false
capitalized? "007, I presume"  #=> false
capitalized? "$100 for that?"  #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
 def capitalized?(str)
   str == str.capitalize 
 end
```